# Changing Docker IP to 10.10.x.x

Tags: macos, docker, sal, kitematic

We are trying to use SAL on OS X. Docker and Kitematic seem to be great, but I cannot understand how to connect to SAL once it has been set up within Kitematic (Docker).

The machine hosting Docker is 10.10.10.15. Docker creates a VM that runs on 192.168.99.100:80, which I cannot get to unless I am on the machine itself. How can I change this, or rather how can I access the Docker VM?

Am I doing something wrong?